# Suppressing errors in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, file-get-contents

I'm running a PHP script every night using a cron service. Everything it outputs will be printed to an log file for debug prepossess. The file I use will retrieve xml's from a different site using the function 'file_get_contents()'. But the function can return an error which I really don't want to see as I am already showing a custom error.

Quick example of my piece of code:

```
$buffer = @file_get_contents('http://xx:xx@xx/xml/xx?offset=2') or print('retry in 5 seconds');

if($buffer === false) {
  sleep(5);
  $buffer = @file_get_contents('http://xx:xx@xx/xml/xx?offset=2') or print('error notice');
}
```

The problem is the first one will trigger an error and print it'll retry in 5 seconds. How can I correctly suppress the thrown error?

I have an error handler, but I prefer not to catch this error separately.

Edited:
My solution wasn't to change the error_reporting, but to catch the error message. If it starts with 'file_get_contents()', no error will be thrown. This is not the best way, but will do the job for me.

Comment: Why are you using or if you want it suppressed?

Comment: Because I want to see all my errors, but this one is not really an error since I catch it with an retry and already print it to the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try inserting this at the start:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Then after the code with the error/warning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```

Comment: The problem is that this is one of the only errors I want to suppress. The other error's still need to be shown.

Comment: @Sietse - See my edit. (And no, I didn't copy it from moidaschl's answer, in case you were wondering.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the other notices still need to be printed tough... When I get an undefined index for example I want to see which one and where it can go wrong. I even use E_STRICT in my error_reporting since my PHP version is below the 5.4

Comment: They will be printed after the second `error_reporting` line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read quite well. Not the nicest way to do this, but it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :-) I know it isn't very nice or polished, but it does do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, never ever use the @-operator.

In PHP you have two options available: either use a custom error handler or use try/catch.

Since file_get_contents doesn't throw an exception, you can only use the first approach.

You can set an error handler like this: http://php.net/set-error-handler and then act correctly (log something or return a custom error code).

If you just want to turn of all errors use `error_reporting(0)` or if you just want to turn off a specific category use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING)` (all but warnings) or specifcy them explicitely `error_reporting(E_WARNING | E_NOTICE)` (warnings and notices).

I prefer the first approach, since when you just disable it you have no idea of what's going on in your code.

Comment: As you stated, I can't use the try-catch here. The error reporting as to be on. I even use a shutdown handler for the E_ERROR's which won't be shown with the normal error_handler. But these error's are the only one I don't wish to show since I'll do a retry and print the error myself. So the custom error handler won't fit for this right? Or is there a way to catch the error thrown by the file_get_contents function separately?

Comment: You can add multiple error handlers that stack on top of each other.. So before calling the method you can use a custom error handler and then remove it afterwards. Does this make sense in your case?

Comment: I found a way to catch the error, but it works with only the normal error handler. I just catch the error in the handle function when the error starts with file_get_contents(). But it is almost the same way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Add @ before command or use try catch.

Comment: As you can see, the @-operator is already in front of the function. Try catch will not work since it will not thrown an exception.